# Setup localhost proxy

Tags: proxy

I am hosting a PWA in a local network. The network is not connected to the internet and is for internal use only. As service-workers require https, which is tricky (at least for me) to set up in a local network, and service-workers are allowed to run from localhost or 127.*, I wondered if I could proxy the local IP of the server hosting the PWA (it's in the 172 address range) to an IP of the 127.* address range on the android phone trying to access the PWA, thus mitigating the requirement for SSL encryption. As it's not connected to the internet and only for internal use, I don't worry about security issues.
Is this possible or is there a smarter way? How would I do it?

Comment: What you are trying to do is far more complex that simply set-up an https server for your network (and import the used certificate on Android. For web browsers like Chrome this works). Because you would not only have to redirect/proxy the traffic but also modify the hostname contained in each HTTP request. Last but not least I don't understand why you post this on an Android site or is the server running on Android?

Comment: Well, there's multiple ways to achieve it and I don't know what's the easiest way. One solution I thought of was the one I proposed here with redirecting/mapping IP ranges on an android device, hence the Android site. If it's easier to setup https on the server and somehow import the certificate, I will do that. Do you know a good resource I could have a look at for that?